# How do I automate onclick redirection to Outlook for creating mail?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

When clicked on supportmailid present in webpage it takes me to Outlook create mail, how do I automate this? I am using selenium for all my automation of web-app.

Comment: By opening outlook, it actually opens your default email client. You can adjust the default email client to a different application and be able to create your scripts from there.

Comment: @PaulMuir I had a similar thought as I read this. I currently have gmail as my default for mailto links and in this scenario I'm pretty sure I could just plow ahead after the click. I think your comment is probably most of an answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is tough scenario to automate Komal. **Using selenium, We are restricted to interact only with web elements.** I have face this issue. Its not possible to automate with outlook.

**Work-around :**

1. You can **get() the support email address from web** page
2. **Write one custom method to send_an_email()**. This will include all the steps of

   - Open browser & visit on specific url
   - Valid login
   - Compose
   - Enter email address of "To", write subject line & actual email text
3. Use **support_email as a input parameter for send_an_email()** method
4. This way you can automate your scenario of sending email to support team.